# Gulp: Error: Cannot find module 'babel/register'

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, salesforce, babeljs

I'm currently working on a project that needed to get upgraded to a new node version. The upgrade worked fine, but now gulp isn't working. Whenever I run gulp i'm getting

**Error message when running gulp**

```
Error: Cannot find module 'babel/register
Require stack:
- /Users/user/project/gulpfile.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/shared/require-or-import.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^4.0.0/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/project/gulpfile.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/user/project/gulpfile.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/shared/require-or-import.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^4.0.0/index.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/index.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js'
  ]
```

**project.json**

```
{
  "name": "sfra",
  "version": "6.3.0",
  "description": "Storefront Reference Architecture",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.11"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "sgmf-scripts --test test/unit/**/*.js",
    "cover": "sgmf-scripts --cover 'test/unit'",
    "test:integration": "sgmf-scripts --integration 'test/integration/**/*.js'",
    "test:acceptance:custom": "npx codeceptjs run --plugins retryFailedStep --profile",
    "test:acceptance:deep": "npx codeceptjs run --plugins retryFailedStep --grep '(?=.*)^(?!.*@mobile)^(?!.*@tablet)^(?!.*@pageDesigner)' --profile",
    "test:acceptance:smoke": "npx codeceptjs run --plugins retryFailedStep --grep @happyPath --profile",
    "test:acceptance:pagedesigner": "npx codeceptjs run --plugins retryFailedStep --grep @pageDesigner --profile",
    "test:acceptance:desktop": "npx codeceptjs run --plugins retryFailedStep --grep '(?=.*)^(?!.*@mobile)^(?!.*@tablet)^(?!.*@pageDesigner)^(?!.*@deepTest)' --profile",
    "test:acceptance:mobile": "npx codeceptjs run --plugins retryFailedStep --profile sauce:phone --grep @mobile",
    "test:acceptance:tablet": "npx codeceptjs run --plugins retryFailedStep --profile sauce:tablet --grep @tablet",
    "test:acceptance:parallel": "npx codeceptjs run-multiple parallel --plugins retryFailedStep --profile",
    "test:acceptance:multibrowsers": "npx codeceptjs run-multiple multibrowsers --plugins retryFailedStep --profile",
    "test:acceptance:report": "./node_modules/.bin/allure serve test/acceptance/report",
    "bdd:snippets": "./node_modules/.bin/codeceptjs bdd:snippets --path",
    "compile:scss": "sgmf-scripts --compile css",
    "compile:js": "sgmf-scripts --compile js",
    "compile:fonts": "node bin/Makefile compileFonts",
    "build": "npm run compile:js && npm run compile:fonts && npm run compile:scss",
    "lint": "npm run lint:css && npm run lint:js",
    "lint:css": "sgmf-scripts --lint css",
    "lint:js": "sgmf-scripts --lint js",
    "init:isml": "./node_modules/.bin/isml-linter --init",
    "lint:isml": "./node_modules/.bin/isml-linter",
    "build:isml": "./node_modules/.bin/isml-linter --build",
    "fix:isml": "./node_modules/.bin/isml-linter --autofix",
    "upload": "sgmf-scripts --upload",
    "uploadCartridge": "sgmf-scripts --uploadCartridge app_storefront_base && sgmf-scripts --uploadCartridge modules && sgmf-scripts --uploadCartridge bm_app_storefront_base",
    "watch": "sgmf-scripts --watch",
    "watch:static": "sgmf-scripts --watch static",
    "release": "node bin/Makefile release --"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/storefront-reference-architecture.git"
  },
  "author": "Ilya Volodin <ivolodin@demandware.com>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/storefront-reference-architecture",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.7",
    "@babel/register": "^7.22.5",
    "@tridnguyen/config": "^2.3.1",
    "@wdio/sauce-service": "^7.20.5",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^5.13.2",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.17.2",
    "appium": "^1.22.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-subset": "^1.6.0",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "cheerio": "0.22.0",
    "cldr-data": "^32.0.1",
    "codeceptjs": "^2.6.11",
    "codeceptjs-cucumber": "^2.0.10",
    "codeceptjs-saucehelper": "^1.4.0",
    "codeceptjs-saucelabs": "^2.0.6",
    "codeceptjs-shared": "^2.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "debug": "^4.1.1",
    "deepmerge": "^3.3.0",
    "dw-utils": "^1.3.136",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^5.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sitegenesis": "~1.0.0",
    "globalize": "^1.4.2",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^3.0.3",
    "grunt-browserify": "^3.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.10.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.2",
    "grunt-external-sourcemap": "^0.1.8",
    "grunt-fswatch-webdav-extended": "^0.1.9",
    "grunt-gh-pages": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-jscs": "^1.8.0",
    "grunt-jsdoc": "^0.6.7",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "^0.12.7",
    "grunt-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-gh-pages": "^0.5.2",
    "gulp-if": "^1.2.5",
    "gulp-jscs": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.1",
    "gulp-mocha": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "handlebars": "^3.0.3",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "isml-linter": "^5.26.4",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "jscs": "^1.13.1",
    "jshint": "^2.8.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.2",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "merge-stream": "^0.1.7",
    "minimist": "^1.2.6",
    "mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "^2.0.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.26",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "properties-parser": "^0.3.1",
    "proxyquire": "1.7.4",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "sass": "^1.51.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "selenium-standalone": "^6.16.0",
    "sgmf-scripts": "^2.4.2",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.5",
    "should": "^13.2.3",
    "sinon": "^1.17.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.13.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^2.5.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "vinyl-transform": "^1.0.0",
    "watchify": "^3.2.3",
    "wdio-sauce-service": "^0.4.14",
    "webdriverio": "^5.14.5",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.22",
    "xtend": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "cleave.js": "^1.5.3",
    "flag-icon-css": "^2.9.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "imagesloaded": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 2 versions",
    "ie >= 10"
  ],
  "packageName": "app_storefront_base",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "env"
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run lint",
      "pre-push": "npm run test"
    }
  }
}
```

I have babel in my package.json, I've deleted node_modules and package lock json. Reran NPM install and gulp. That didn't seem to fix the issue. I can see babel in the package.json, so I'm not really sure why it's saying its missing. Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this problem?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by running

```
npm i @babel/register
npm i @babel/core
npm i gulp@3.9.0
npm i promise
npm install
```

Comment: Fun fact: 
`npm i @babel/register @babel/core gulp@3.9.0 promise && npm install`